# Bookmark Lines with positive $ amounts in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text doc with about 9000 lines.  The data is alpha numeric.  Within the doc, there are approximately 150 lines I need to identify.  The only common factor is that each contains a dollar amount.  I've tried multiple Regex searches, and just can't get it right.

```
       INVALID PAYMENT AMT
 013  1887000  CRJ        0.00 03/04/2015-01222015 - Code 938
       INVALID PAYMENT AMT
 019        0 ,CRJ      426.72 03/06/2015-01282015 - Code 628
```

In the example above, I need to bookmark the line with the 426.72.  I don't care about the other 3 lines.  Every line I need in the document has a positive dollar amount.

Comment: Try `^\s+[A-Z\ ]+\r\n.*[^\d](\d+\.\d+).*$` in the replace tab, on the find field. Use `$1` at the replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately, ^\s+[A-Z ]\r\n.*(\d+\.\d+) .*$ doesn't find anything when I execute it.

Comment: Awesome, gtgaxiola!  That did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

`(([1-9][0-9]*)\.([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]|00)*)|(0\.([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]))`

Comment: I'm missing one group.  It's giving me anything that has a decimal greater than zero (96.50), but nothing with an even dollar amount (96.00).  Thoughts?

Comment: will revise the regex for it. (But now it will give you 0.00 as well)

Comment: changed it... (do you have to account for amounts such as 0.53?)

Comment: Yes.  I need to account for anything greater than 0.00.